# How to start itemize on same line as text?

Tags: lists, environments, itemize

I've created a new environment called 'Example' like this:

```
\newenvironment{example}
    {\textbf{Example:} \begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}}
```

The environment works fine, but the items are starting after the **Example:** text. Is it possible to start with the first item on the same line as the **Example:** text and vertically aline the rest of the items with the first item?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want all the bullets horizontally aligned with the first one that is in the same line as “Example”? If this is what you want, I recommend you not to do it.

Comment: @egreg: I'd like to align the bullets vertically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it, but I wouldn't recommend it. Look at the result and judge for yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newlength{\jeroenlen}
\newenvironment{example}
 {\settowidth{\jeroenlen}{\textbf{Example:}}%
  \begin{description}[leftmargin=\jeroenlen,labelwidth=0pt,labelsep=0pt]
  \item[\textbf{Example:}]%
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.5em,labelsep=.5em]}
 {\end{itemize}\end{description}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{example}
\item Such and such
\item So and so
\item Enough
\end{example}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The enclosing `description` environment is necessary for avoiding a line break after “Example:”.

[image]

Comment: The only problem there, visually, is the bullets. If you take them out, and just have the items with no markers, it would look fine.

Comment: @crmdgn I can agree, but that seems what the OP wants.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{example}
    {\textbf{Example:}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\linewidth}\begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  \item These are first examples.
  \item Second examples.
  \item And more.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about a page break?

Answer (score 2):

Using enumitem, you also can have a slightly different layout, where the label of the first item (Example •) is centred with respect to the bullets of the following items, which looks better in my opinion. Here's the result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\pagestyle{empty}  
\parindent = 0pt  

\makeatletter%  
\newenvironment{examples}{%  
\newsavebox{\Exbox}\newlength{\len}%  
\sbox{\Exbox}{\textbf{Examples}\enspace\textbullet}\settowidth{\len}{\usebox{\Exbox}}%  
\let\olditem\item  
\def\item{\if@newlist\olditem\hspace{0.5\len}\else\olditem\fi}  
\setlist{before=\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\if@newlist\makebox[0pt]{\usebox{\Exbox}}\else\textbullet\fi}}  
\begin{itemize}[labelwidth =0.5\len,itemindent=!,leftmargin=!]}%  
{\end{itemize}}  
\makeatother%  

\begin{document}
 Let’s try  this:   
\begin{examples}%   
\item very first element of the list,    
\item second element,  
\item third element.  
\end{examples}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm this is kind of cheating. It's just inserting the Examples text on the same line as the list starts. It's not actually removing the linebreak.