# Make items directly following the words, without a new line.

Tags: itemize

Normally, if using `itemlize` we should get the following appearance:

```
There are following methods:
\begin{itemlize}
    \item Method A
    \item Method B
\end{itemlize}
```

There are following methods:

- Method A
- Method B

However, I want no new line after the first line, like:
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Probably itemize within a minipage or a tabular.

Comment: Where does the `itemlize` environment come from?

Comment: @azetina, could you provide me with some code?

Comment: Related: [How to start itemize on same line as text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147710/how-to-start-itemize-on-same-line-as-text)

Comment: @C.Wang The link provided by Papiro is enough. See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147717/10898