# Itemize inside a paragraph

Tags: itemize

I would like to be able to start an itemize environment after a sentence, on the same line of the sentence, and indent from that point on.

Something like 
-exactly what I'm doing

-here but the second item should be aligned with the first one.

Edit: This is for a presentation in beamer, I would like to use this to save space on a slide.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: you may want to take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147710/how-to-start-itemize-on-same-line-as-text

Comment: what would you like to happen if the introductory text takes up more than half the line, and the item text is long?  also, presumably, if the introductory text goes to more than one line, you want the item list to begin at that point?

Comment: it's inside one slide of a presentation so it's just a very small paragraph.
in general if the item were long enough to start a new line, I would like it to begin aligned with the rest of the item.

Comment: @dcmst 
following the link I saw that I could use a minipage, but in that example they always want the same text in front of the list, while I want the possibility of changing it.

Comment: @claudia, just add an argument so that you can change the text. Also, please note that since it is for a (beamer?) presentation, the solutions involving the `enumitem` package may misbehave.

Comment: @closers Since the OP added (in a comment) that this is for a presentation I'm not sure this is a duplicate given that the other question is not about presentations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a definition of an environment that can be used to obtain the look you want.

```
  \newenvironment{OLitemize}[1][\linewidth]
     {\begin{minipage}[t]{#1}\begin{itemize}}
     {\end{itemize}\end{minipage}
    }
```

Usage is then:

```
bla bla bla  \begin{OLitemize} \item test 1 \item test 2 \end{OLitemize}
```

One remark to this code: I expect you to normally just put small parts of text after each `\item`.  Since I reserve a whole linewidth for the `minipage`, long texts will hang out on the right side of the page. For this case, one can pass an optional parameter to `OLitemize` which is the width of the space you want to use. This can be used to fit long texts on your page.

Perhaps one could even improve the definition by calculating how much space is left on the page and then pass this as an argument to the `minipage`. Unfortunately, my LaTeX-abilities do not allow do this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you select code and hit Ctrl+K, or click the button marked `{}`, it will be highlighted as such.

Comment: it doesn't work as I want in beamer, it leaves a line before the itemize begins. I had tried it in an article before and it worked, also inside a theorem environment.