# How to start itemization on same line as text using beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning, itemize

I am making a presentation and instead of [image]

I want the first item appear right next to "betrachte".
So it is basically what is asked and answered in [How to start itemize on same line as text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147710/how-to-start-itemize-on-same-line-as-text)
but I could not get it working with beamer.
Can anyone help?

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{228,230,231}
%Zitate und todos
\usepackage{url}

% Reelle, Natürliche, Ganze, Rationale Zahlen
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand{\N}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}

% Fraktur für Strukturen
\newcommand{\A}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak A}}
\newcommand{\B}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak B}}
\newcommand{\C}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak C}}
\newcommand{\D}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak D}}
\newcommand{\I}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak I}}

% Makros für logische Operatoren
\newcommand{\xor}{\ensuremath{\oplus}} %exklusives oder
\newcommand{\impl}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}} %logische Implikation
\newcommand{\Impl}{\ensuremath{\Rightarrow}}

\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}
\renewcommand{\theta}{\vartheta}
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\w}{\omega}
\renewcommand{\*}{\cdot}

\title{Title}
%\subtitle{Subtitle Here}
\author{author}
\institute{}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{$ (\N, \*)  $ ist nicht-automatisch}
    \begin{block}{}
        Monoide mit Submonoid $ (\N, \*) $ sind nicht-automatisch.
    \end{block}
    ang. doch\\
    Betrachte 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $ \{|p|_L: p\text{ prim} \land |p|_L \leq n\} = \{a_0 <_{llex} ... <_{llex} a_{r_{n-1}}\}$\\
        \item $ F_n = \{ a_0^{\beta_0} \* ... \* a_{r_{n-1}}^{\beta_{r_{n-1}}}: 0 \leq \beta_i < 2^n\} $.
    \end{itemize}
    abschätzen mit s.o.:\\ 
    Einzelne Faktoren: $ |a_i^{\beta_i}|_L \textcolor{red}{\leq} |a_i|_L + p_{\*} \lceil log(\beta_i)\rceil \leq n + p_{\*} \lceil log(\beta_i)\rceil \leq n(1+p_{\*})$. \\
    Konkretes Produkt: $ | a_0^{\beta_0} \* ... \* a_{r_{n-1}}^{\beta_{r_{n-1}}}|_L \leq n(1+p_{\*}) + p_{\*} \lceil log(r_n)\rceil $\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable. (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). How are `\N` and `\*` defined?

Comment: Your code currently results in an error message since you define a command `\C` which is already defined. Since you use a lot of single-letter macros, you might want to take a look at [Single letter macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316391/134144) and [Short names for macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19111/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a tabular is sufficient?

[image]

```
    Betrachte
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\textbullet\ }l}
      $ \{|p|_L: p\text{ prim} \land |p|_L \leq n\} = \{a_0 <_{llex} ... <_{llex} a_{r_{n-1}}\}$\\
      $ F_n = \{ a_0^{\beta_0} \* ... \* a_{r_{n-1}}^{\beta_{r_{n-1}}}: 0 \leq \beta_i < 2^n\} $.
    \end{tabular}
    
    abschätzen mit s.o.:\\
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!