# Remove linebreak before first itemize item

Tags: itemize, enumitem, vertical-spacing

I have a list where I want the first bullet to start on the same line as the preceding text. My current example is this. In the image I've marked where I want the bullet to be located:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Heading}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][2]
        \item \lipsum[1][3]
        \item \lipsum[1][4]
        \item \lipsum[1][5]
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a similar question to [How to start itemize on same line as text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147710/how-to-start-itemize-on-same-line-as-text), but none of these solutions work for me, because they either involve creating a new minipage which indents *all* the bullets, not just the first, or they hardcode the preceding text, which won't work for me.

Anyway, since each `\item` seems to automatically be placed on a newline, I thought it would be as simple as adding a command to "undo" the newline at the start of the list, e.g.

```tex
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{before=\nolinebreak}
```

I repeated this with `before=\unskip` but neither worked.

Is there no simple command I can put in `before=` to prevent this first line break? If not, why is it so complex?

Answer (score 3):

A `trivlist` attempt, which simulates the case when a theorem-like environment starts with a list:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \trivlist\item[\textbf{Heading}\hskip-\labelsep]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1][2]
        \item \lipsum[1][3]
        \item \lipsum[1][4]
        \item \lipsum[1][5]
    \end{itemize}
    \endtrivlist
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wish there were a way to integrate this into the regular itemize list using `enumitem` etc

Answer (score 2):

**Quick and dirty:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Heading}
\vspace{-5ex}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2.5cm]
        \item \lipsum[1][2]
        \item \lipsum[1][3]
        \item \lipsum[1][4]
        \item \lipsum[1][5]
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

**Second attempt, only indenting the first item:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Heading}
\vspace{-5ex}

\begin{itemize}
 {\setlength\itemindent{1.25cm} \item \lipsum[1][2]}
        \item \lipsum[1][3]
        \item \lipsum[1][4]
        \item \lipsum[1][5]
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Third attempt, measure offset automatically:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\foobar}

\def\myheading{My longer Heading}

    \settowidth{\foobar}{\textbf{\myheading}}
    {\textbf{\myheading}}

\vspace{-5ex}

\begin{itemize}
 {\setlength\itemindent{\foobar} \item \lipsum[1][3]}
        \item \lipsum[1][2]
        \item \lipsum[1][4]
        \item \lipsum[1][5]
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Right, but the issue with that is that it indents *all* the bullets, which as I mentioned in the question isn't what I want. I would rather just the first one be indented.

Comment: Yes, I realized that, you were just too quick to comment. See my revised, second example above.

Comment: I don't love that I have to manually adjust by the length of the preceding text, but this does work

Comment: You can always use `\settowidth` to (semi-) automate things. I am lacking the time to put this all in a proper macro, but to see how it's done, check out my (again) revised code.